# How I need to configure grunt-string-replace to copy and replace a directory tree?

Tags: javascript, node.js, grunt-string-replace

I need to replace a Text in a directory tree and copy to another folder. I'm using grunt text-replace plugin and Glob npm. you could  see the config next:

```
replace: {
    replace2: {
        src: 'js/app/circo/**/*.js',
        dest: 'js/app/circo2/',
        replacements: [{
            from: 'app/payasos',              
            to: 'app/funambulistas'
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

This settings replace the text and copy all the file into the ***js/app/circo2/***  folder and the tree disappear.

I try to change the dest to:

```
dest: 'js/app/circo2/**',
```

but this show this error:

> Running "replace:replace2" (replace) task
>   Warning: Unable to read "js/app/circo/" file (Error code: EISDIR). Use --force to continue.

Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish when changing the `dest`

Comment: I'm try to copy the directory tree. it's just a test.

Comment: @MoolsBytheway Glob documentation say: _** If a "globstar" is alone in a path portion, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches. It does not crawl symlinked directories._

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally use two Grunt plugin: copy and replace. that the configuration:

```
copy: {
    main: {
        files: [
            {expand: true,  cwd: 'js/app/circo/',src: '**', dest: 'js/app/circo2/'}
        ]
    }

},

replace: {
    replace2: {     
        src: 'js/app/circo2/**/*.js',
        overwrite:true,
        replacements: [{
            from: 'app/payasos',              
            to: 'app/funambulistas'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

First copy the file making all src relative to cwd. You can see the setting [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) .

Secondly, I replace from 'app/payasos' to 'app/funambulistas' in the **js/app/circo2/**/*.js** src (all js files in directory and sub-directories inside circo2 folder). on both configurations is used the "globstar". You can see more info about glob [here](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).

That work for me but I'm sure that it possible do it using replace.